# Why am I getting "undefined reference to `dladdr'" even with -ldl for this simple program?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation, linker, llvm

I'm working through an [LLVM Tutorial](http://llvm.org/releases/2.6/docs/tutorial/JITTutorial1.html), but I'm having trouble compiling. I've written a minimal example that reproduces the issue:

```
#include "llvm/Module.h"
#include "llvm/LLVMContext.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    llvm::Module *module = new llvm::Module("test", llvm::getGlobalContext());
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile, I get a bunch of 'undefined reference' erros:

```
clang++ `llvm-config --cxxflags`   -c -o test.o test.cpp
clang++  test.o  `llvm-config --ldflags --libs core` -o test
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Signals.o): In function `PrintStackTrace(void*)':
(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `dladdr'
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Signals.o): In function `PrintStackTrace(void*)':
(.text+0x1f6): undefined reference to `dladdr'
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Mutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::MutexImpl::MutexImpl(bool)':
(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Mutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::MutexImpl::MutexImpl(bool)':
(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Mutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::MutexImpl::MutexImpl(bool)':
(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared'
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Mutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::MutexImpl::MutexImpl(bool)':
(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Mutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::MutexImpl::tryacquire()':
(.text+0x179): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::RWMutexImpl()':
(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_init'
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::~RWMutexImpl()':
(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_destroy'
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::reader_acquire()':
(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_rdlock'
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::reader_release()':
(.text+0xe9): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock'
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::writer_acquire()':
(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_wrlock'
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::writer_release()':
(.text+0x149): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock'
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Threading.o): In function `llvm::llvm_execute_on_thread(void (*)(void*), void*, unsigned int)':
(.text+0x1cc): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Threading.o): In function `llvm::llvm_execute_on_thread(void (*)(void*), void*, unsigned int)':
(.text+0x208): undefined reference to `pthread_attr_setstacksize'
/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Threading.o): In function `llvm::llvm_execute_on_thread(void (*)(void*), void*, unsigned int)':
(.text+0x228): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

If I view the manpage for dladdr, it says that I need to link with `-ldl`. But I'm already doing that with `llvm-config`:

```
$ llvm-config --ldflags --libs core
-L/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib  -lpthread -lffi -ldl -lm 
-lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport -L/usr/lib/llvm-2.9/lib
```

Additionally, `-ldl` appears in the correct order (i.e., after the `.o` file that requires the symbols).

I'm at a loss for the next step in debugging this issue. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm running LVVM 2.9-7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The library requiring the symbols is included by `-lLLVMSupport`, so `-ldl` must come after `-lLLVMSupport`. I changed this:

```
`llvm-config --ldflags --libs core`
```

To this:

```
`llvm-config --libs core` `llvm-config --ldflags`
```

And the linker was successful.

Answer (score 12):

I was having the same issue when going through the LLVM tutorial for llvm-3.4, and unfortunately, the answer from Matthew didn't help. For future reference, I'm posting a new answer with the problems I ran into and how I fixed it.

I have installed LLVM in `~/dev/llvm/install`, so I was using the command given in the tutorial, but replaced `llvm-config` with the path for my llvm installation:

```
clang++ -g -O3 toy.cpp `../llvm/install/bin/llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs core` -o toy
```

I got a ton of errors, the first one was:

```
filipe@filipe-Kubuntu:~/dev/kaleidoscope$ clang++ -g -O3 toy.cpp `../llvm/install/bin/llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs core` -o toy
In file included from toy.cpp:1:
In file included from /home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/include/llvm/IR/Verifier.h:24:
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/include/llvm/ADT/StringRef.h:342:14: error: no template named 'enable_if' in namespace 'std'; did you mean
      '__gnu_cxx::__enable_if'?
    typename std::enable_if<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed, bool>::type
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             __gnu_cxx::__enable_if
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/ext/type_traits.h:43:12: note: '__gnu_cxx::__enable_if' declared here
    struct __enable_if 
           ^
```

This is because at this point LLVM requires a C++11 compiler; adding `-std=c++11` to `clang++` options solved it. But then I got:

```
filipe@filipe-Kubuntu:~/dev/kaleidoscope$ clang++ -std=c++11 -g -O3 toy.cpp `../llvm/install/bin/llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs core` -o toy
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Process.o): In function `terminalHasColors(int)':
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Process.inc:273: undefined reference to `setupterm'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Process.inc:291: undefined reference to `tigetnum'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Process.inc:295: undefined reference to `set_curterm'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Process.inc:296: undefined reference to `del_curterm'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Signals.o): In function `llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(_IO_FILE*)':
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:278: undefined reference to `dladdr'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:290: undefined reference to `dladdr'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Mutex.o): In function `MutexImpl':
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Mutex.cpp:53: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Mutex.cpp:59: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Mutex.cpp:67: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Mutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::MutexImpl::tryacquire()':
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Mutex.cpp:109: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `RWMutexImpl':
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/RWMutex.cpp:59: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_init'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `~RWMutexImpl':
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/RWMutex.cpp:72: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_destroy'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::reader_acquire()':
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/RWMutex.cpp:82: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_rdlock'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::reader_release()':
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/RWMutex.cpp:92: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::writer_acquire()':
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/RWMutex.cpp:102: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_wrlock'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::writer_release()':
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/RWMutex.cpp:112: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.o): In function `ThreadLocalImpl':
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/ThreadLocal.cpp:56: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.o): In function `~ThreadLocalImpl':
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/ThreadLocal.cpp:63: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.o): In function `llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::setInstance(void const*)':
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/ThreadLocal.cpp:70: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.o): In function `llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::getInstance()':
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/ThreadLocal.cpp:77: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/install/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Threading.o): In function `llvm::llvm_execute_on_thread(void (*)(void*), void*, unsigned int)':
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Threading.cpp:91: undefined reference to `pthread_attr_setstacksize'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Threading.cpp:96: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/home/filipe/dev/llvm/llvm/lib/Support/Threading.cpp:100: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Contrary to what happened with the author of the original question, I noticed `llvm-config` was not even linking against any system library. Then I figured that I needed to use `--system-libs` in order to include the desired system libraries into the linking process:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -g -O3 toy.cpp `../llvm/install/bin/llvm-config --cppflags --libs core --ldflags --system-libs` -o toy
```

It is important to always put `--system-libs` in the end, so that all missing dependencies are brought in by the linker.

Tested with LLVM 3.4 and Kubuntu 14.04

Comment: I also needed --system-libs to successfully compile with clang 3.5. They make this wonderfully modular set of libraries and then it's nigh-impossible to link against them.