# How do I link when building with llvm libraries?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, static-analysis, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am trying to parse a LLVM-IR file(.ll) and do a static analysis..

I found this sample code below, and I tried to build it, but I don't know which library to link.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h"
#include "llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"

using namespace llvm;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        errs() << "Expected an argument - IR file name\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    LLVMContext &Context = getGlobalContext();
    SMDiagnostic Err;
    std::unique_ptr<Module> Mod = parseIRFile(argv[1], Err, Context);

    if (Mod) {
        std::cout << "Mod is not null" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
       std::cout << "Mod is null" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I gave the below command to build, and it gives me some undefined reference error, which that I think is a linking error.

```
g++ -I~/llvm/build/include -I~/llvm/llvm/include  -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

Which library file should I have to link with -L option in order to build this sample code? I want this to work as a standalone binary, not as a pass within the whole compile procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you setup your project as a subproject of llvm, you may read [this tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/Projects.html) and [examples](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/tree/master/examples).

But since you mentioned "standalone" I guess you tried to build your project out of llvm source project. `llvm-config` is your friend.

For example, you can find that inside [tools/llvm-link](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/tree/master/tools/llvm-link)'s `Makefile` reads:

```
LINK_COMPONENTS := linker bitreader bitwriter asmparser irreader
```

or in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS
  BitWriter
  Core
  IRReader
  Linker
  Support
  )
```

Then you can use `llvm-config` to see how to link these libs.

```
$ llvm-config --libs linker bitreader bitwriter asmparser irreader
```

or

```
$ llvm-config --libs BitWriter Core IRReader Linker Support
```

They will output the link options like:

```
-lLLVMLinker -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMMC -lLLVMIRReader -lLLVMBitReader -lLLVMAsmParser -lLLVMBitWriter -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport
```

`llvm-config --components` can be used to see all the official components; if you are tired with specifying components, simply use `llvm-config --libs` and it will emit *all* linkable libraries.

Of course you should firstly make sure the library directory is in your link path, which is the result `llvm-config --libdir`.

You can use `llvm-config --help` for other useful options.

Comment: I've tried this, but it still gave me undefined reference, so I've searched a little bit more and found this page(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993460/why-am-i-getting-undefined-reference-to-dladdr-even-with-ldl-for-this-simpl)  and resolved the problem. Thanks, anyway.